# Drawing the Tangent of 3D Curve Data Points in an Artificial Neural Network From Scratch

Tags: python, math, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on building an Artificial Neural Network (ANN) from scratch, and I have a set of 3D curve data points representing the output of the network. I'm interested in visualizing the tangents of the curve at various points. How can I draw the tangents of these 3D curve data points within the context of my ANN implementation? What are the steps and code examples I should follow to achieve this?

[image: My ANN architecture is looking like this]

My primary goal is to identify and visualize the decision boundaries of the data points processed by my ANN. Additionally, I would like to trace the tangents of these decision boundaries.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to determine these decision boundaries and effectively trace the tangents using Python or any relevant tools or libraries? Any code examples or insights into the implementation would be highly valuable.

Thank you for your assistance!

[image]

Comment: `Could someone please provide guidance on how to determine these decision boundaries and effectively trace the tangents using Python or any relevant tools or libraries?` so you're saying, you don't know how to do this conceptually? In that case, if you couldn't do this without code, then asking on a site to help with coding questions might be jumping the gun; [this list of sites[(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) might be a better starting point, potentially.

Comment: what does the graph drawing have to do with the ANN? Just find the gradient for X and Y on a point and draw the plane, **NOT** a line